# properties of feasible sets of an optimisation problem

Tags: general-topology, analysis, optimization

Assume the feasible region $\Omega$ of an optimisation problem is determined by $m_E$ equality constraints $c_k(x) = 0$ and $m_I$ inequality constraints $c_l(x) \leq 0$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all $c_k$s are continuously differentiable on a larger open set containing $\Omega$. My professor gave two claims on class which seem pretty intuitive but I find it difficult to prove. I hope someone can tell me if the following results are correct and if so, how to prove them?

1. if the interior of $\Omega$ is nonempty, then there is no equality constraints, i.e., $m_E = 0$
2. if $x$ is in the interior of $\Omega$, then $c_l(x) < 0$ for all $l$ in $m_I$, i.e., none of the inequality constraint is tight

I can show $\Omega$ must be closed, but failed to proceed to any meaningful direction.